# C# POCO Generation from SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, code-generation, poco

Is there a way of generating POCO classes from a SQLite database?
Similar to how sqlmetal can do for sql server?

Not looking for something quite so "heavy" as codesmiths...

Comment: an online tool just for that: https://codverter.com/src/sqltoclass?prg=1&db=5&sample=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework maybe?  You can gen EF objects from database then modify the generated classes as you need.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use this with SQLite?

Comment: Get the .NET VS Integration package at http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki  I use this one because VS integration isn't working with the most current.  Then there are literally thousands of tutorials including video tutorials on the net with using Entity Framework.  There is no difference except choosing SQLite provider instead of SQL Server or ADODB or OLEDB.

Comment: ok cool, will i be able to generate poco classes from an existing sqlite db schema doing this?

Comment: yup, my current project is a sqlite db file with 12 tables in 3rd normal form with foreign key relationships and constraints and the entity framework POCOs work like a charm....Really cool.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but my feet got me here looking for such a tool and someone else might benefit from this nifty generator I've found:

http://salardbcodegenerator.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps.